# Snowflake SQL MERGE Statement executes successfully but fails in a procedure

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I have a snowflake MERGE statement that executes successfully on its own but when I wrap it in a procedure, it is complaining about one of the columns "invalid identifier".

This is my SQL statement:

```
MERGE INTO WAREHOUSE.ART_TWITTER_TRANSACTION_FACT t 
USING (
with artist_twitter as  
(select lower(trim(twitter_handle_1)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_1 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_1 is not null 
and twitter_handle_1 is not null
and twitter_id_1 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_1)), twitter_id_1

union 

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_2)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_2 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_2 is not null 
and twitter_handle_2 is not null
and twitter_id_2 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_2)), twitter_id_2

union  

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_3)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_3 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_3 is not null 
and twitter_handle_3 is not null
and twitter_id_3 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_3)), twitter_id_3

union  

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_4)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_4 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_4 is not null 
and twitter_handle_4 is not null
and twitter_id_4 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_4)), twitter_id_4

union  

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_5)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_5 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_5 is not null 
and twitter_handle_5 is not null
and twitter_id_5 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_5)), twitter_id_5


)
, count_artist_by_twitter_handle as  
(  
select trim(a.twitter_handle) as twitter_handle, count(distinct b.artist_name) as unique_artists
from artist_twitter a
inner join warehouse.artist_dim b 
on a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_1 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_2 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_3 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_4 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_5 
where b.twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by trim(a.twitter_handle)
)

, count_art_by_artist as  
(  
select a.artist_name
, lower(trim(c.twitter_handle)) as twitter_handle
, count(distinct a.collection_contract_uid || '-' || a.collection_item_id) as unique_art
, row_number() over (partition by lower(trim(c.twitter_handle)) order by unique_art desc) as rank
from warehouse.art_dim a 
inner join warehouse.artist_dim b 
on a.artist_name = b.artist_name
inner join artist_twitter c 
on (c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_1 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_2 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_3 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_4 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_5 )
group by a.artist_name, lower(trim(c.twitter_handle))
order by lower(trim(c.twitter_handle)), rank

)

, pick_ranked_artist as  
(  
  select 
  artist_name 
  ,twitter_handle 
  from count_art_by_artist
  where rank = 1
)

, twitter_handle_artist_cnt_ranked as  
(select a.twitter_handle, a.unique_artists, 
case when b.artist_name is not null then b.artist_name 
    else c.artist_name end artist_name
from count_artist_by_twitter_handle a 
left join pick_ranked_artist b 
on a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle
left join (select twitter_handle_1 as twitter_handle, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_1 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_2, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_2 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_3, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_3 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_4, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_4 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_5, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_5 is not null
          ) c 
on a.twitter_handle = c.twitter_handle
)

, artist_twitter_associations as 
(select 
 a.tweet_id 
,a.tweet_conversation_id
,a.twitter_author_id
,b.twitter_id 
,b.twitter_handle
,c.artist_name
,a.tweet_url 
,a.tweet_expanded_url
,a.tweet_display_url
,a.tweet_unwound_url
,a.tweet_text 
,a.tweet_url_status
,a.tweet_url_title
,a.tweet_url_description
,a.tweet_public_retweet_count
,a.tweet_public_reply_count
,a.tweet_public_like_count
,a.tweet_public_quote_count
,a.as_of_datetime
,a.tweet_date
,row_number() over (partition by a.tweet_id order by a.as_of_datetime desc) as rank
from stage.twitter_tweet_history a 
left join artist_twitter b 
on a.twitter_author_id = b.twitter_id 
left join twitter_handle_artist_cnt_ranked c 
on b.twitter_handle = c.twitter_handle
group by  
 a.tweet_id 
,a.tweet_conversation_id
,a.twitter_author_id
,b.twitter_id 
,b.twitter_handle
,c.artist_name
,a.tweet_url 
,a.tweet_expanded_url
,a.tweet_display_url
,a.tweet_unwound_url
,a.tweet_text 
,a.tweet_url_status
,a.tweet_url_title
,a.tweet_url_description
,a.tweet_public_retweet_count
,a.tweet_public_reply_count
,a.tweet_public_like_count
,a.tweet_public_quote_count
,a.as_of_datetime
,a.tweet_date
) 

,ranked_tweet_associations as  
(
select 
 tweet_id 
,tweet_conversation_id
,twitter_author_id
,twitter_id 
,twitter_handle
,artist_name
,tweet_url 
,tweet_expanded_url
,tweet_display_url
,tweet_unwound_url
,tweet_text 
,tweet_url_status
,tweet_url_title
,tweet_url_description
,tweet_public_retweet_count
,tweet_public_reply_count
,tweet_public_like_count
,tweet_public_quote_count
,as_of_datetime
,tweet_date
from artist_twitter_associations 
where rank = 1
)

, derive_link_info as  
(select  tweet_id, twitter_author_id, twitter_handle, artist_name,
as_of_datetime, tweet_date,
case when tweet_unwound_url is null  
    then tweet_expanded_url 
    else tweet_unwound_url end as url_to_parse
from ranked_tweet_associations
)

, split_url as  
(   
  select tweet_id, twitter_author_id, twitter_handle, artist_name
  , as_of_datetime, tweet_date
  , url_to_parse
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 0) as site_url_0
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 1) as site_url_1
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 2) as site_url_2
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 3) as site_url_3
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 4) as site_url_4
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 5) as site_url_5
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 6) as site_url_6
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 7) as site_url_7
  , case when site_url_3 = 'niftygateway.com'
      then 'nifty'
      else 'other' end as site 
  , case when site = 'nifty' and site_url_4 = 'collections'
      then site_url_5 
      when site = 'nifty' and site_url_4 = 'profile'
      then site_url_5 
      when site = 'nifty' and site_url_4 = 'itemdetail'
      then site_url_6 
      else 'Other'
      end as artist_info
  from derive_link_info
)

,identify_art_or_artist as  
(  
  select a.tweet_id
  , a1.tweet_conversation_id
  , a.twitter_author_id
  , a.twitter_handle
  , a.artist_name as tweet_artist_name
  , a.as_of_datetime
  , a.tweet_date
  , a1.tweet_text
  , a1.tweet_public_retweet_count 
  , a1.tweet_public_reply_count
  , a1.tweet_public_like_count 
  , a1.tweet_public_quote_count
  ,a1.tweet_url
  ,a1.tweet_expanded_url
  ,a1.tweet_display_url
  ,a1.tweet_unwound_url
  ,a1.tweet_url_status
  ,a1.tweet_url_title
  ,a1.tweet_url_description  
  , a.url_to_parse
  , a.site_url_4
  , a.site_url_5
  , a.site_url_6
  , a.site_url_7
  , a.site 
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then  
          case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then b.artist_name 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then c.artist_name
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then a.site_url_5 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then d.artist_name
          end
      else 'Other' end as art_artist_name
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then b.collection_contract_uid 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then c.collection_contract_uid
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then 'None'
          end
      else 'None' end as collection_contract_uid 
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then b.collection_item_id 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then 'None'
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then 'None'
          end
      else 'None' end as collection_item_id
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then a.site_url_7
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then 'None'
          end
      else 'None' end as token_id             
  
  from split_url a 
  inner join ranked_tweet_associations a1 
  on a.tweet_id = a1.tweet_id
  left join warehouse.art_dim b 
  on a.site_url_6 = b.collection_contract_uid 
  and a.site_url_7 = b.collection_item_id
  left join ( select collection_contract_uid, artist_name
              from warehouse.art_dim 
              group by collection_contract_uid, artist_name) c 
  on a.site_url_6 = c.collection_contract_uid 

  left join (select artist_name from warehouse.art_dim 
            group by artist_name) d 
  on a.site_url_5 = d.artist_name
)
select  
 a.tweet_id 
,a.collection_contract_uid 
,a.collection_item_id 
,a.token_id
,a.tweet_artist_name 
,a.twitter_handle as tweet_twitter_handle
,a.art_artist_name 
,NVL(b.art_name,'None') as art_name
,a.tweet_text
,a.tweet_conversation_id
,a.twitter_author_id
,a.tweet_date
,a.tweet_public_retweet_count
,a.tweet_public_reply_count
,a.tweet_public_like_count
,a.tweet_public_quote_count
,a.tweet_url
,a.tweet_expanded_url
,a.tweet_display_url
,a.tweet_unwound_url
,a.tweet_url_status
,a.tweet_url_title
,a.tweet_url_description
,a.as_of_datetime 
,current_timestamp
from identify_art_or_artist a
left join warehouse.art_dim b 
on a.collection_contract_uid = b.collection_contract_uid
and a.collection_item_id = b.collection_item_id

) s 
ON s.tweet_id = t.tweet_id 
AND s.collection_contract_uid = t.collection_contract_uid
AND s.collection_item_id = t.collection_item_id
AND s.token_id = t.token_id
AND s.tweet_artist_name = t.tweet_artist_name
AND s.tweet_twitter_handle = t.tweet_twitter_handle
AND s.art_artist_name = t.art_artist_name
AND NVL(s.art_name,'None') = NVL(t.art_name,'None')
AND s.tweet_text = t.tweet_text
AND s.tweet_conversation_id = t.tweet_conversation_id
AND s.twitter_author_id = t.twitter_author_id
AND s.tweet_date = t.tweet_date 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url,'x')
AND NVL(s.tweet_expanded_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_expanded_url,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_display_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_display_url,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_unwound_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_unwound_url,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url_status,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url_status,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url_title,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url_title,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url_description,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url_description,'x') 
AND s.tweet_public_retweet_count = t.tweet_public_retweet_count
AND s.tweet_public_reply_count = t.tweet_public_reply_count
AND s.tweet_public_like_count = t.tweet_public_like_count
AND s.tweet_public_quote_count = t.tweet_public_quote_count
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 

(
 tweet_id 
,collection_contract_uid 
,collection_item_id 
,token_id
,tweet_artist_name 
,tweet_twitter_handle
,art_artist_name 
,art_name
,tweet_text
,tweet_conversation_id
,twitter_author_id
,tweet_date
,tweet_public_retweet_count
,tweet_public_reply_count
,tweet_public_like_count
,tweet_public_quote_count
,tweet_url
,tweet_expanded_url
,tweet_display_url
,tweet_unwound_url
,tweet_url_status
,tweet_url_title
,tweet_url_description
,as_of_datetime 
,insert_date
)
VALUES

(s.tweet_id 
,s.collection_contract_uid 
,s.collection_item_id 
,s.token_id
,s.tweet_artist_name 
,s.tweet_twitter_handle
,s.art_artist_name 
,s.art_name
,s.tweet_text 
,s.tweet_conversation_id
,s.twitter_author_id 
,s.tweet_date 
,s.tweet_public_retweet_count
,s.tweet_public_reply_count
,s.tweet_public_like_count
,s.tweet_public_quote_count
,s.tweet_url 
,s.tweet_expanded_url
,s.tweet_display_url
,s.tweet_unwound_url
,s.tweet_url_status
,s.tweet_url_title
,s.tweet_url_description
,s.as_of_datetime
,current_timestamp)
;
```

And this is the same exact statement placed in a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure NFT_DEV_DB.WAREHOUSE.load_art_twitter_transaction_fact()
  returns string 
  language javascript
  execute as owner
  as
  $$

// Construct the merge sql statement  
// Snowflake currently only supports a single sql statement execution in a procedure.
//     Due to this limitation, sql updates and inserts must be formatted as a merge statement.
// This procedure loads new or changed tweets from landing.twitter_tweet_changes to stage.twitter_tweet_history.
//      It will check each field for changes so if a tweet comes through on multiple twitter pulls it will only 
//      be inserted if there is something different since the last pull of that record.

    var sql_command = 
    `
MERGE INTO WAREHOUSE.ART_TWITTER_TRANSACTION_FACT t 
USING (
with artist_twitter as  
(select lower(trim(twitter_handle_1)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_1 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_1 is not null 
and twitter_handle_1 is not null
and twitter_id_1 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_1)), twitter_id_1

union 

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_2)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_2 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_2 is not null 
and twitter_handle_2 is not null
and twitter_id_2 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_2)), twitter_id_2

union  

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_3)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_3 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_3 is not null 
and twitter_handle_3 is not null
and twitter_id_3 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_3)), twitter_id_3

union  

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_4)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_4 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_4 is not null 
and twitter_handle_4 is not null
and twitter_id_4 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_4)), twitter_id_4

union  

select lower(trim(twitter_handle_5)) as twitter_handle, twitter_id_5 as twitter_id 
from warehouse.artist_dim
where twitter_id_5 is not null 
and twitter_handle_5 is not null
and twitter_id_5 <> '0'
and twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by 
lower(trim(twitter_handle_5)), twitter_id_5


)
, count_artist_by_twitter_handle as  
(  
select trim(a.twitter_handle) as twitter_handle, count(distinct b.artist_name) as unique_artists
from artist_twitter a
inner join warehouse.artist_dim b 
on a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_1 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_2 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_3 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_4 
or a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_5 
where b.twitter_filter_flag = 1
group by trim(a.twitter_handle)
)

, count_art_by_artist as  
(  
select a.artist_name
, lower(trim(c.twitter_handle)) as twitter_handle
, count(distinct a.collection_contract_uid || '-' || a.collection_item_id) as unique_art
, row_number() over (partition by lower(trim(c.twitter_handle)) order by unique_art desc) as rank
from warehouse.art_dim a 
inner join warehouse.artist_dim b 
on a.artist_name = b.artist_name
inner join artist_twitter c 
on (c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_1 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_2 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_3 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_4 
or c.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle_5 )
group by a.artist_name, lower(trim(c.twitter_handle))
order by lower(trim(c.twitter_handle)), rank

)

, pick_ranked_artist as  
(  
  select 
  artist_name 
  ,twitter_handle 
  from count_art_by_artist
  where rank = 1
)

, twitter_handle_artist_cnt_ranked as  
(select a.twitter_handle, a.unique_artists, 
case when b.artist_name is not null then b.artist_name 
    else c.artist_name end artist_name
from count_artist_by_twitter_handle a 
left join pick_ranked_artist b 
on a.twitter_handle = b.twitter_handle
left join (select twitter_handle_1 as twitter_handle, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_1 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_2, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_2 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_3, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_3 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_4, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_4 is not null
          union  
          select twitter_handle_5, artist_name from warehouse.artist_dim
          where artist_type = 'NON-ARTIST'
          and twitter_handle_5 is not null
          ) c 
on a.twitter_handle = c.twitter_handle
)

, artist_twitter_associations as 
(select 
 a.tweet_id 
,a.tweet_conversation_id
,a.twitter_author_id
,b.twitter_id 
,b.twitter_handle
,c.artist_name
,a.tweet_url 
,a.tweet_expanded_url
,a.tweet_display_url
,a.tweet_unwound_url
,a.tweet_text 
,a.tweet_url_status
,a.tweet_url_title
,a.tweet_url_description
,a.tweet_public_retweet_count
,a.tweet_public_reply_count
,a.tweet_public_like_count
,a.tweet_public_quote_count
,a.as_of_datetime
,a.tweet_date
,row_number() over (partition by a.tweet_id order by a.as_of_datetime desc) as rank
from stage.twitter_tweet_history a 
left join artist_twitter b 
on a.twitter_author_id = b.twitter_id 
left join twitter_handle_artist_cnt_ranked c 
on b.twitter_handle = c.twitter_handle
group by  
 a.tweet_id 
,a.tweet_conversation_id
,a.twitter_author_id
,b.twitter_id 
,b.twitter_handle
,c.artist_name
,a.tweet_url 
,a.tweet_expanded_url
,a.tweet_display_url
,a.tweet_unwound_url
,a.tweet_text 
,a.tweet_url_status
,a.tweet_url_title
,a.tweet_url_description
,a.tweet_public_retweet_count
,a.tweet_public_reply_count
,a.tweet_public_like_count
,a.tweet_public_quote_count
,a.as_of_datetime
,a.tweet_date
) 

,ranked_tweet_associations as  
(
select 
 tweet_id 
,tweet_conversation_id
,twitter_author_id
,twitter_id 
,twitter_handle
,artist_name
,tweet_url 
,tweet_expanded_url
,tweet_display_url
,tweet_unwound_url
,tweet_text 
,tweet_url_status
,tweet_url_title
,tweet_url_description
,tweet_public_retweet_count
,tweet_public_reply_count
,tweet_public_like_count
,tweet_public_quote_count
,as_of_datetime
,tweet_date
from artist_twitter_associations 
where rank = 1
)

, derive_link_info as  
(select  tweet_id, twitter_author_id, twitter_handle, artist_name,
as_of_datetime, tweet_date,
case when tweet_unwound_url is null  
    then tweet_expanded_url 
    else tweet_unwound_url end as url_to_parse
from ranked_tweet_associations
)

, split_url as  
(   
  select tweet_id, twitter_author_id, twitter_handle, artist_name
  , as_of_datetime, tweet_date
  , url_to_parse
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 0) as site_url_0
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 1) as site_url_1
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 2) as site_url_2
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 3) as site_url_3
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 4) as site_url_4
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 5) as site_url_5
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 6) as site_url_6
  , split_part(url_to_parse, '/', 7) as site_url_7
  , case when site_url_3 = 'niftygateway.com'
      then 'nifty'
      else 'other' end as site 
  , case when site = 'nifty' and site_url_4 = 'collections'
      then site_url_5 
      when site = 'nifty' and site_url_4 = 'profile'
      then site_url_5 
      when site = 'nifty' and site_url_4 = 'itemdetail'
      then site_url_6 
      else 'Other'
      end as artist_info
  from derive_link_info
)

,identify_art_or_artist as  
(  
  select a.tweet_id
  , a1.tweet_conversation_id
  , a.twitter_author_id
  , a.twitter_handle
  , a.artist_name as tweet_artist_name
  , a.as_of_datetime
  , a.tweet_date
  , a1.tweet_text
  , a1.tweet_public_retweet_count 
  , a1.tweet_public_reply_count
  , a1.tweet_public_like_count 
  , a1.tweet_public_quote_count
  ,a1.tweet_url
  ,a1.tweet_expanded_url
  ,a1.tweet_display_url
  ,a1.tweet_unwound_url
  ,a1.tweet_url_status
  ,a1.tweet_url_title
  ,a1.tweet_url_description  
  , a.url_to_parse
  , a.site_url_4
  , a.site_url_5
  , a.site_url_6
  , a.site_url_7
  , a.site 
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then  
          case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then b.artist_name 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then c.artist_name
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then a.site_url_5 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then d.artist_name
          end
      else 'Other' end as art_artist_name
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then b.collection_contract_uid 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then c.collection_contract_uid
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then 'None'
          end
      else 'None' end as collection_contract_uid 
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then b.collection_item_id 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then 'None'
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then 'None'
          end
      else 'None' end as collection_item_id
  , case when a.site = 'nifty'
      then case when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'primary'
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'itemdetail' and a.site_url_5 = 'secondary'
          then a.site_url_7
          when a.site_url_4 = 'profile' 
          then 'None' 
          when a.site_url_4 = 'collections'
          then 'None'
          end
      else 'None' end as token_id             
  
  from split_url a 
  inner join ranked_tweet_associations a1 
  on a.tweet_id = a1.tweet_id
  left join warehouse.art_dim b 
  on a.site_url_6 = b.collection_contract_uid 
  and a.site_url_7 = b.collection_item_id
  left join ( select collection_contract_uid, artist_name
              from warehouse.art_dim 
              group by collection_contract_uid, artist_name) c 
  on a.site_url_6 = c.collection_contract_uid 

  left join (select artist_name from warehouse.art_dim 
            group by artist_name) d 
  on a.site_url_5 = d.artist_name
)
select  
 a.tweet_id 
,a.collection_contract_uid 
,a.collection_item_id 
,a.token_id
,a.tweet_artist_name 
,a.twitter_handle as tweet_twitter_handle
,a.art_artist_name 
,NVL(b.art_name,'None') as art_name
,a.tweet_text
,a.tweet_conversation_id
,a.twitter_author_id
,a.tweet_date
,a.tweet_public_retweet_count
,a.tweet_public_reply_count
,a.tweet_public_like_count
,a.tweet_public_quote_count
,a.tweet_url
,a.tweet_expanded_url
,a.tweet_display_url
,a.tweet_unwound_url
,a.tweet_url_status
,a.tweet_url_title
,a.tweet_url_description
,a.as_of_datetime 
,current_timestamp
from identify_art_or_artist a
left join warehouse.art_dim b 
on a.collection_contract_uid = b.collection_contract_uid
and a.collection_item_id = b.collection_item_id

) s 
ON s.tweet_id = t.tweet_id 
AND s.collection_contract_uid = t.collection_contract_uid
AND s.collection_item_id = t.collection_item_id
AND s.token_id = t.token_id
AND s.tweet_artist_name = t.tweet_artist_name
AND s.tweet_twitter_handle = t.tweet_twitter_handle
AND s.art_artist_name = t.art_artist_name
AND NVL(s.art_name,'None') = NVL(t.art_name,'None')
AND s.tweet_text = t.tweet_text
AND s.tweet_conversation_id = t.tweet_conversation_id
AND s.twitter_author_id = t.twitter_author_id
AND s.tweet_date = t.tweet_date 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url,'x')
AND NVL(s.tweet_expanded_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_expanded_url,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_display_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_display_url,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_unwound_url,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_unwound_url,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url_status,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url_status,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url_title,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url_title,'x') 
AND NVL(s.tweet_url_description,'x') = NVL(t.tweet_url_description,'x') 
AND s.tweet_public_retweet_count = t.tweet_public_retweet_count
AND s.tweet_public_reply_count = t.tweet_public_reply_count
AND s.tweet_public_like_count = t.tweet_public_like_count
AND s.tweet_public_quote_count = t.tweet_public_quote_count
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 

(
 tweet_id 
,collection_contract_uid 
,collection_item_id 
,token_id
,tweet_artist_name 
,tweet_twitter_handle
,art_artist_name 
,art_name
,tweet_text
,tweet_conversation_id
,twitter_author_id
,tweet_date
,tweet_public_retweet_count
,tweet_public_reply_count
,tweet_public_like_count
,tweet_public_quote_count
,tweet_url
,tweet_expanded_url
,tweet_display_url
,tweet_unwound_url
,tweet_url_status
,tweet_url_title
,tweet_url_description
,as_of_datetime 
,insert_date
)
VALUES

(s.tweet_id 
,s.collection_contract_uid 
,s.collection_item_id 
,s.token_id
,s.tweet_artist_name 
,s.tweet_twitter_handle
,s.art_artist_name 
,s.art_name
,s.tweet_text 
,s.tweet_conversation_id
,s.twitter_author_id 
,s.tweet_date 
,s.tweet_public_retweet_count
,s.tweet_public_reply_count
,s.tweet_public_like_count
,s.tweet_public_quote_count
,s.tweet_url 
,s.tweet_expanded_url
,s.tweet_display_url
,s.tweet_unwound_url
,s.tweet_url_status
,s.tweet_url_title
,s.tweet_url_description
,s.as_of_datetime
,current_timestamp)
;
`
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
          sqlText: sql_command
          }
          );                    
    
 try {
        var result1 = stmt.execute();
        result1.next();
        return "Succeeded.";   // Return a success/error indicator.
        }
    catch (err)  {
        return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
        } 


  $$
;
```

I had a different version of this procedure running before (similar code just made some code changes due to changed data and fields) and it ran fine. Is there a character limit that I might be running into or something? I can't see any other reason for this failure.

This is the error I receive:

> Failed: SQL compilation error: error line 11 at position 12
> invalid identifier 'TWITTER_HANDLE'

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but I don’t understand your comment at the start of the SP. Why do you think an SP only supports a single SQL statement - you can run as many as you like, though only one at a time, if that’s what you mean?

Comment: Since you mention that you had a previous version that was working before, it's possible you have an overloaded stored procedure and your edits aren't having effect because the call is running a different overload. You can run `show procedures;` to see if you have multiple versions of the SP. If you do, make sure you're calling the one with the parameter signature you're editing.

Comment: When I tried to run multiple sql statements, it gave me an error at execution saying it could only run one sql statement. Maybe I just didn't construct it properly. I was trying to use temp tables at the time.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with overload as no version had a parameter included. Changing the cte to a view solved the problem, which led me to believe there's some kind of limitation of characters or the procedure was otherwise confused with the number of cte's I was using.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was to pull out all the CTE code into a view and just reference the view after USING. That seems to work, so I'm wondering if Snowflake has a character limitation of some kind for procedures. I haven't seen any mention of one in my searching on the internet so far. So, I guess this is resolved for now.